# removing differencies of some text pairs

Tags: linux, perl, text

Some days ago I asked a question about tagging differencies in 2 text files, and was answered quickly.

now I have a rather similar question but a bit more complicated.
I have 2 pair of files by the following characteristics:
pair1: (File1.txt , File2.txt)
pair2: (File3.txt , File4.txt)

There is a line by line correspondence between each files in these pairs. say that File1.txt and File3.txt are some English words, and File2.txt and File4.txt are their Arabic and French translations respectively. In addition, File1.txt and File3.txt are very similar (and in some cases the same).

```
    File1.txt       File2.txt
    EnWord1         ArTrans1
    EnWord2         ArTrans2
    EnWord3         ArTrans3
    Enword4         ArTrans4

    File3.txt       File4.txt
    EnWord1         FrTrans1
    EnWord3         FrTrans3
    Enword4         FrTrans4
    Enword5         FrTrans5
```

Now what I want to do is to compare English sides of these pairs, find the common words that appear in both files (EnWord1,EnWord3, and EnWord4) and filter out their corresponding translations.
In short, I can say that using two bilingual English-Arabic and English French dictionaries, I am trying to build a 3-lingual English-Arabic-French dictionary.
How it is possible?

I have to add that since there are many such pairs (the dictionaries are stored in different files, each file contains a part of the words, and by some reasons it is not possible to merge files and then process them) the speed of the code is very important and I am looking for a fast way to do this.

Finally, please give me some points (or even possible the complete code) to do this in Perl.

Best regards,
Hakim

Comment: What size does your files have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the order you would like to maintain follows `File1.txt`. The following `perl` should accomplish what your looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @pair1 = `paste -d ":" $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1]`;
my @pair2 = `paste -d ":" $ARGV[2] $ARGV[3]`;

my @pairs = (@pair1, @pair2);
my (%seen, @dups);

foreach (@pairs)
{
  my $word = (split ":", $_)[0];
  push @dups, $word if $seen{$word}++;
}

open (FILE0, ">", "NEW_File0.txt") or die;
open (FILE1, ">", "NEW_File1.txt") or die;
open (FILE2, ">", "NEW_File2.txt") or die;

foreach my $duplicate (@dups)
{
  print FILE0 "$duplicate\n";

  foreach (@pair1) { print FILE1 ((split ":", $_)[1]) if $_ =~ /^$duplicate:/; }
  foreach (@pair2) { print FILE2 ((split ":", $_)[1]) if $_ =~ /^$duplicate:/; }
}

close FILE0;
close FILE1;
close FILE2;
```

Run like this:

```
./script.pl File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt File4.txt
```

---

`grep "" NEW_File*` results:

```
NEW_File0.txt:EnWord1
NEW_File0.txt:EnWord3
NEW_File0.txt:EnWord4
NEW_File1.txt:ArTrans1
NEW_File1.txt:ArTrans3
NEW_File1.txt:ArTrans4
NEW_File2.txt:FrTrans1
NEW_File2.txt:FrTrans2
NEW_File2.txt:FrTrans3
```

May not be the most efficient way to do things, but should give you somewhere to start at least. HTH.

Comment: Dear Steve, I think working with unicode files is another difficulty in my case. Since the files may contain semicolon, double quote and some other special characters, I decided to use default <b>paste</b> separator (tab character "\t") but trying to split files using "\t" it  faces some problems and causes the Arabic and French files to be empty, while English file is not...

Answer (score 2):

Consider this as hint, i haven't verified this

```
join <(paste file.1 file.2) <(paste file.3 file.4)
```

Comment: I can verify that it works. Just add `> file.5` to write the result to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

This will be rough code in Perl for this.

```
%Dict1 = map { /^(.+),(.+)$/ } `paste file1.txt file2.txt -d,`;
%Dict2 = map { /^(.+),(.+)$/ } `paste file3.txt file4.txt -d,`;

print "Col1,Col2,Col3";
print "$_,$d1{$_},$d2{$_}\n" foreach (keys %k) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to merge files, each language must be in a separate file, but their must be a 1 to 1 correspondence between files. according to the example I discussed in the first post, after finishing the process, the contents of the files must be as follows:

```
File1.txt:
EnWord1         
EnWord3
Enword4
```

```
File2.txt:
ArTrans1         
ArTrans3
ArTrans4
```

```
File4.txt:
FrTrans1
FrTrans3
FrTrans4
```

As I explained in that example, EnWord1, EnWord3, and EnWord4 are the common English words in both File1.txt and File3.txt.

The important thing that must keep in mid is that both File1 and File3 are in English which share some words. I need to first find the common lines of these files and store them in another file (say File5.txt) and then filter File2 and File4 in a way that they contain only the translations of words that are stored in File5.

Comment: Rozuur solution fits your requirement perfectly. Once joined, you can use **[cut](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-columns-cut.html)**  to put them in separate file.

Comment: No, it doesn't. because it doesn't remove differences, and also merges File1,File2,File3, and File4 together. I mean the output of this script is as follows:  (line i of File1.txt) (line i of File2.txt) (line i of File3.txt) (line i of File4.txt)

Comment: did you ran it? coz i get only 3 columns. Note that for join to work file1.txt & file3.txt should be sorted.

Comment: I have to mention that I can't sort the files. This means that files must be treated as they are. It is an obligation...

Comment: Clarify why you can't sort the files.

Comment: @Hakim, I think `File4.txt` should contain FrTrans1, FrTrans2, FrTrans3. Is this correct?

Comment: No Steve. According to the first post, we see that only EnWord1, EnWord3, and EnWord4 are in both English files. So File4.txt must contain just the translations of these words, which means FrTrans1, FrTrans3, and FrTrans4

Comment: @Hakim, SO is not a forum: rather than adding answers containing additional information, please edit your question concisely. In regards to the numbers that correspond to the `FrTrans` var, please edit these into the question to avoid confusion.