# How to build a 4language dictionary from bilingual dictionaries

Tags: linux, perl, text, nlp

3 days ago I asked a question about building a parallel dictionary which has 3 languages: [removing differencies of some text pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135928/removing-differencies-of-some-text-pairs)

The question was as follows:
 I have 2 pair of files by the following characteristics: pair1: (File1.txt , File2.txt) pair2: (File3.txt , File4.txt)

There is a line by line correspondence between each files in these pairs. say that File1.txt and File3.txt are some English words, and File2.txt and File4.txt are their Arabic and French translations respectively. In addition, File1.txt and File3.txt are very similar (and in some cases the same).

```
    File1.txt       File2.txt
    EnWord1         ArTrans1
    EnWord2         ArTrans2
    EnWord3         ArTrans3
    Enword4         ArTrans4

    File3.txt       File4.txt
    EnWord1         FrTrans1
    EnWord3         FrTrans3
    Enword4         FrTrans4
    Enword5         FrTrans5
```

What I wanted to do then, was to compare English sides of the pairs, find the common words that appear in both files (EnWord1,EnWord3, and EnWord4) and filter out their corresponding translations.
In short, I can say that using two bilingual English-Arabic and English French dictionaries, I am trying to build a 3-lingual English-Arabic-French dictionary.

Steve answered me and wrote a nice code to find duplicated English words and remove others and their translations: [The answer could be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141345/1265960)

But I still have a bit more complicated question:
What should I do, if I want to add another language? I mean that I have another English-Russian dictionary (Say File5.txt contains English entities, and File6.txt contains Russian entities) and I want to build a 4-language dictionary instead of a 3-language one.

one way is to build a 3-language dictionary using the current code, and then by rerunning it on a new language pair, build a 4-language dictionary. but I think it is not efficient enough, and it would be better solution to this problem. It also may bring in some inconsistencies in other languages.
My main challenge is checking the duplications: when have just 2 language pairs, it would be very easy to check the duplications. But what should I do if I want to check the duplications in 3 pairs?
How can I change the code to be able to extract 4language dictionary in just one pass?

Comment: Beware, word for word translation doesn't work because of semantic and usage/collocation differences, not to mention idioms, phrasal verbs, slang and such.

Comment: Yes Alex. You're right. But as I mentioned in my previous question, I don't want to build a translation engine. what I want to do is to compile a 4-language dictionary using 3 bilingual dictionaries (English-Arabic, English-French, and English-Russian). Working on a 3-language dictionary is easier, because checking duplications is easier, but I dont know to check whether an English word is in all the 3 pairs or not. I have to add that these dictionaries contain phrases, idioms and even short sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll describe a generic approach that I would use in this task.

1) define `%dictionary` hash. Each key of this hash would be an English word, and each value would be, in turn, a reference to another hash containing that word' translations. Something like this:

```
my %dictionary = ( 
  'EnWord1' => { 
     arabic => 'Arabic EnWord1', 
     french => 'French EnWord1',
     ...
  },
  ...
);
```

(this hash will be empty before we start processing files, I'm just showing a structure here).

2) Scan each pair of files simultaneously, add a corresponding record to this hash. There's a simple approach:

```
my %filenames = (
  'arabic' => ['File1.txt', 'File2.txt'],
  'french' => ['File3.txt', 'File4.txt'],
  ...
);

for my $lang (keys %filenames) {
  open my $efh, '<', $filenames{$lang}[0] or die $!, "\n";
  open my $tfh, '<', $filenames{$lang}[1] or die $!, "\n";
  while (<$efh>) {
    chomp(my $enLine = $_);
    chomp(my $trLine = <$tfh>);
    $dictionary{$enLine}{$lang} = $trLine;
  }
}
```

3) Refine `%dictionary`: leave only those elements, which have translations defined in all languages scanned...

```
my $proper_translations_count = scalar keys %filenames;
for my $word (keys %dictionary) {
  my $translations = $dictionary{$word};
  if (scalar keys %$translations != $translations_count) {
    delete $dictionary{$word};
  }
}
```

4) Output `%dictionary` any way suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Perl, but i would work with hash maps.
2 hash maps for each language.
A global identifier (an intermediate language) for the meaning, which works on all dictionaries. So english word x has id1, while id1 in arabic is word y.
So one hash map maps the words onto the the global identifier and the other hashmap maps the global identifier onto the actual word. So you can translate every word from one language to an other with 2 hashmap calls (dict1.get(word):id dict2ID.get(id))

If you want an easier solution, use english as your intermediate language, but then you will get some mistakes in those dictionaries.

Adding new dictionaries would be quiet easy. You just get a file with english to that language and use the english2intermediate hash map to get the identifiers for the new language.